# Getting pixels' colors from screen quickly on macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: macos, colors, applescript, pixel

I'm trying to get pixels' colors from the screen with AppleScript.

These lines in AppleScript work but it's too slow.

```applescript
do shell script "screencapture -R340,1240,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && 
              xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | 
              sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"
```

I only need to be able to run something from an AppleScript script and get the colours somewhere in a variable of the AppleScript script. I found several solutions, but the topics are really old (2010-2011), and what they propose does not work on macOS Catalina.

For example, this with carbon doesn't work:

```c
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
if(argc < 3) {
   printf("Deux arguments ou plus, Syntax : schTrouvePixel <x> <y>\n");
exit(1);
}
int j = (argc - 1) / 2;
int i,n;
unsigned char *addr;

for(i=0; i < j; i++) {
   n = (i * 2) + 1;
   addr = (unsigned char*)CGDisplayAddressForPosition(CGMainDisplayID( ),atoi(argv[n]),atoi(argv[n + 1]));
   printf("%d %d %d\n",addr[2],addr[1],addr[4]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Is it a once-off test, or do you need to keep monitoring it repeatedly?

Comment: I need it to get the colours multiple times. I sometime only need to get the colour of 1 pixel and sometime need to get 50+ pixel's colors.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Do you need to get the pixels 30 times a second or once every 5 seconds? Do you know the coordinates of the pixels you want in advance? Are they all over the screen or all quite close together? Are there hundreds of sets of coordinates or just 2 or three?

Comment: I need to get the pixels 30 times a second. The coordinates of the pixels are all quite close together (approximately in a rectangle of 200*70 pixels because the rectangles don't all have the same width and length). There are hundreds of sets of coordinates and they all depends of a cursor which goes through the rectangle.

Comment: You have zero chance of doing any image processing at 30 fps with Applescript, IMHO.

Comment: That's why I'm searching a solution using other langages to get the colors, and get/send the colors to my script.

Comment: I don't believe there's even a mechanism in Applescript to communicate with anything at 30 times per second.